# js, ссылки, работа с данными

Tags: javascript

Делая работу, я столкнулся с тем, что я не знаю можно ли при переходе на страничку передать передать некоторые данные для другого js файла.

Поясняю. у меня есть страница с 10 ссылками и они будут только отличаться содержанием двух div'ах т.е. я могу создать один шаблон и вставлять туда текст.
Понятно что нужно убрать ссылки и поставить onclick на текст. Осталось понять как через js реализовать переход на ссылку с определёнными даннымы, чтобы другой скрипт увидел эти данные и внес в эти div'ы.

и да это работа по информатике и поэтому серверов точно не будет.

Comment: ни фига не понятно

Comment: вероятно надо добавить ваши параметры в запрос типа localhost?var1=data1&var2=....

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko я уже сказал,что эта работа по информатике и нету не каких апачи. Всё запускается из файла.

Comment: спасибо, надеюсь в школах буду учить культере общения прежде информатики